# How can I get data from multiple fireStore collections in React native?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have these Collections:

- User(Uid = document) with name and image,
- Post(Uid Post =  doucment) includes body, image and Uid (Uid user)

I am using nested loops to have a simple object (I do not use 2 arrays)

```
firebase.firestore().collection("Post").get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
               querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                    this.setState({
                        dataPost: this.state.dataPost.concat({
                            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                            key: documentSnapshot.id,
                            name: this.getUserbyUid(documentSnapshot.data().uid) <- get Name user as soon as I get the uid from the Post collection
                        }),
                    })
              });
      });
  getUserbyUid = (Uid) => {
            firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc(Uid).get()
            .then(documentSnapshot => {
                return documentSnapshot.data().name
            })}
```

I get an error `name: Undefinded`

This is the way I think, I know there are many better ways please help me tks

## Post

[image]

## User

[image]

```
Object {
  "body": "hfdbdb"
  "date": 1614903953253,
  "image": “"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/t.....-44¢5-b091-7af310de36d1",
  "key": "IX9KKfcOONSyquUtossTd",
  "name": undefined,
  "uid": "Chc1P3zcWMguc2d2ppKSRrpQx752",
},
```

[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NQ8E.png)

Answer (score -1):

You need to review your data structure first because as your database grows, looping and extracting data can become very complex.

You can read more about the different [data structures here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data). Each has a different set of pros and cons, and choosing one will depend on your use case.

Once you have a good database foundation, your code will become cleaner and easier to read.

As an example in Python:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore


cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'projectId': 'test-project',
})

db = firestore.client()
```

## Get User Data

```py
users = db.collection('User').document('document')

user = users.get()

print(f'Data: {user.to_dict()}')

. . .

Data: {'avatar': 'http://my-avatar-image.com',
       'name': 'My Good Name'}
```

## Get Post Data

```py
posts = db.collection('Post').document('document')

post = posts.get()
 
print(f'Data: {post.to_dict()}')

. . .

Data: {'date': '121445475589',
       'body': 'sdfsdfsdf',
       'uid': 'Hyhyfd987698IUHGKDSh8d',
       'image': 'http://my-example-image.com'
}
```

## Get Documents in a Collection

```py
users = db.collection(u'User').stream()

for user in users:
    print(f'{user.id} => {user.to_dict()}')

. . . 

document => {'avatar': 'http://my-avatar-image.com', 'name': 'My Name'}
document1 => {'avatar': 'http://my-avatar-image.com', 'name': 'My Good Name'}
```

## Get Documents from a Collection Group

```py
users = db.collection(u'Users')

a_posts = users.document(u'A').collection(u'post')
a_posts.document().set({
    u'name': u'My Good Name',
    u'type': u'user'
})

b_posts = users.document(u'B').collection(u'post')
b_posts.document().set({
    u'name': u'My Best Name',
    u'type': u'user'
})

c_posts = users.document(u'C').collection(u'post')
c_posts.document().set({
    u'name': u'My Real Name',
    u'type': u'user'
})

names = db.collection_group(u'post')\
    .where(u'type', u'==', u'user')

all_users = names.stream()

for user in all_users:
    print(f'{user.id} => {user.to_dict()}')
```

## Possible Error Message

You might receive this error message if you create the database and then try extracting the data straightaway. Wait a few minutes while the index is built in the background, and then try again.

```sh
FailedPrecondition: 400 The query requires a COLLECTION_GROUP_ASC index for collection . . That index is not ready yet.
```